# How can I use this regex in Haskell?

Tags: regex, haskell

I'm trying to make a simple Haskell program that will take any line that looks like `someFilenameHere0035.xml` and returns `0035`. My sample input file, input.txt, would look like this:

```
someFilenameHere0035.xml
anotherFilenameHere4465.xml
```

And running: `cat input.txt | runhaskell getID.hs` should return:

```
0035
4465
```

I'm having so much difficulty figuring this out. Here's what I have so far:

```
import Text.Regex.PCRE

getID :: String -> [String]
getID str = str =~ "([0-9]+)\\.xml" :: [String]

main :: IO ()
main = interact $ unlines . getID
```

But I get an error message I don't understand at all:

```
• No instance for (RegexContext Regex String [String])
 arising from a use of ‘=~’
• In the expression: str =~ "([0-9]+)\\.xml" :: [String]
   In an equation for ‘getID’:
   getID str = str =~ "([0-9]+)\\.xml" :: [String] (haskell-stack-ghc)
```

I feel like I'm really close, but I don't know where to go from here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is for learning Haskell: great! Otherwise it seems like you might just want to throw the standard command line tools at this. `grep -o '[0-9]\+\.xml' | sed 's/.xml//'` seems to work, and you could probably do it with a single `sed` command if you don't mind it looking a bit less comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you only want the number part so we can get rid of the `\\.xml`.

The regex-pcre library defines an instance for `RegexContext Regex String String` but not `RegexContext Regex String [String]` hence the error.

So if we change the type signature to `String -> String` then that error is taken care of.

`unlines` expects [String] so to test what we had at this point I wrote a quick function that wraps its argument in a list (there's probably a nicer way to do that but that's not the point of the question):

```
toList :: a -> [a]
toList a = [a]
```

Running your command with `main = interact $ unlines . toList . getID` output 0035, so we're almost there.

`getID` is passed a String of the file contents, these are conveniently separated by the `\n` character. So we can use `splitOn "\n"` from the Data.List.Split library to get our list of .xml files.

Then we simply need to map `getID` over that list (`toList` is no longer needed).

This gives us:

```
import Text.Regex.PCRE
import Data.List.Split

getID :: String -> String
getID str = str =~ "([0-9]+)"

main :: IO ()
main = interact $ unlines . map getID . splitOn "\n"
```

This gives me the desired output when I run your command.

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: The original regex may have been deliberately chosen, e.g. if they were expecting one possible filename to be `foo3bar4.xml`.

Comment: @DanielWagner If that were the case then the example input.txt file should have included such a case. I just provided something that gave the desired output for the example input.